# Generating HTML based on search functions result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working in ASP.NET MVC 5 and I want to generate HTML based on the search functions result. A simple filter that filters on Title. This is how I want the accordion to look.

```js
//Accordion-----------------------------------------------
$(".accordion-desc").fadeOut(0);
$(".accordion").click(function() {
  $(".accordion-desc").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
  $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
});


$(".accordion").click(function() {
  $(".accordion").not(this).find(".rotate").removeClass("down");
  $(this).find(".rotate").toggleClass("down");
});
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: #2cc185;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2em 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  background-color: #2cc185;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #239768;
  color: #fff;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: #239768;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #74777b;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/*Rotation-------------------------------------*/

.accordion .fa {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.rotate.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/*------------------------------------------*/

.link {
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.accordion h4 {
  position: relative;
  /* top: 0.8em; */
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
}

.accordion a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: #74777b;
  padding: 1em 1em 2.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2cc185;
  background-color: #e7ecea;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.accordion-desc {
  background-color: #f1f4f3;
  color: #74777b;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

@media (min-width:480px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1000px;
  }
}

.accordion-desc p {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.accordion .status {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 20%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.heading {
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.heading h2 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.heading .searcheBar {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkboxInput {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  right: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="acc" class="accordion">
  <a href="#">
    <h4 id="title"></h4>
    <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="accordion-desc">
  <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
  <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
  <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
  <p id="description">
    <p>
      <div class="link">
        <a id="link" class="btn btn-success" href="">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to show a snippet of the malfunctioning code, but could not get it to work as a snippet. But here it is flat:

```
    $("#searcheBar").on("keyup", function () {

    var input = "";
    input = this.value;

    var strInput = globalModel;//Array from Ajax call
    var accordionWrapper = document.getElementById("acc");
    var myHtml = "";
    for (i = 0; i < strInput.length; i++) {
        if (strInput[i]["Title"].indexOf(input) > -1) {
            myHtml += '<a href=""><h4 id="title">' + (strInput[i]["Title"]) + '</h4><h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4><i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i></a> </div><div class="accordion-desc"><h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3><h4>Kay Wiberg</h4><p id ="description">' + (strInput[i]["Description"]) + '<p><div class="link"><a id="link" class ="btn btn-success" href="' + (strInput[i]["Url"]) + '">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a></div></div>';

        }


    }
    accordionWrapper .innerHTML = myHtml;

});//OnKey up
```

I am perhaps going in the wrong direction, but I wanted to try and build a search function for my self at first. What I wish is that a full list of items will be shown at first and  On keyup the search function should filter the content. But if the search box is emptied the full list should reappear. I am retrieving the content with an Ajax call that returns an array. As of now i am not populating the code with data on initial load of the dom. Was going to use the same idea as this , but this method messes up the classes and click event.

Answer (score 0):

Is the last line supposed to be 
    accordionWrapper.innerHTML instead of accordion.innerHTML?

Comment: Yes, fixed it, wanted to make the code easier to understand, but forgot to update all accordions

Comment: doesn't jquery use this.val() instead of this.value to get the current value of an input?

Comment: I get this when using `.this.val()` `Uncaught TypeError: this.val is not a function`

Comment: Hmm. maybe try doing input = $("#searchBar").val()

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the event object into the function:

```
$("#searcehBar").on("keyup", function (evt) {

    var input = "";
    input = evt.target.value;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. went back to my initial build with strongly typed model and the using `jquery` to `.show()` and `hide()` the element. `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()`

```
    $("#searcheBar").on("keyup", function () {
    var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".accordion #title").each(function () {
        var s = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        if (s.indexOf(g) !== -1) {
            $(this).parent().parent().fadeIn();
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```